# find and extract shortened urls from string

Tags: javascript

I want to remove a url from a string looking like this:

## Guardian #Tech #News: "Hillsborough report: what data journalism can tell us about the files" http://t.co/kplfDhLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegEx is a way of dealing with strings, just not my preferred one. If same thing is true for you, then try this:

```
var text = 'Guardian #Tech #News: ...snipped... http://t.co/kplfDhLE';
text.substring(0, text.indexOf("http"));    // Gives only the text
text.substring(text.indexOf("http"));       // Gives only the URL
```

If the URL isn't at the end of the string, then it get's a little tricky, but still a lot better than killing yourself with regex.

Comment: how can you make it detect links like this as well "reut.rs/NZBkVF" or "orgu.com/p/3acyv/tf" ?

Comment: "but still a lot better than killing yourself with regex." I disagree strongly. Regexes are a useful skill to have. String manipulation methods only get you so far.

Comment: Not to start a flame-war, but a great hacker once said: **"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  _Now they have two problems_."** - jwz [[citation](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)]; I have a similar ideology.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to pick out the url:

```
var reg = /(\bhttps?:\/\/[\w|\d|\.|-|\/]+\b)/gi,
    result = reg.exec(tweet)[0];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4rtEb/

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = str.match(/\bhttps?:[^\s]+\b/i)[0];
```